# Line chart with hourly-daily data

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following temperature data:

```
1/1/2019 9:00AM 18.5
1/1/2019 5:00PM 21.3
2/1/2019 8:00AM 23.6
2/1/2019 5:00PM 20.8
2/1/2019 9:00PM 13.4
```

I can get a plot with the x-axis as either date or time. But would like to plot the temperature at these time points nested within the dates.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community User 14 times.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), {A1:A+B1:B, C1:C}, ))
```

[image]